# Finding thread using TID

Tags: c++, multithreading, windows-embedded-compact

I am building an application based on wec7. I have the following thread:

```
bool ChannelDataQueue::b_ChannelDataQueue_StartThread()
{
   m_hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ChannelDataQueue::u32_ChannelDataQueue_ReadChannelData, (LPVOID)this, CREATE_SUSPENDED, NULL);

   CeSetThreadPriority(m_hThread,CE_THREAD_PRIO_256_HIGHEST);
  //SetThreadPriority(m_hThread,249);//248
  ResumeThread(m_hThread);

  return true;
}
```

I am using the remote tools in VS2008 to monitor the processes and threads, but the threads only show up with the process they are in and TID/PID. I dont know how to determine which thread i am monitoring based on its ID.

Answer (score 0):

The last parameter to the [CreateThread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) call is a pointer to a DWORD that will receive the thread ID.

Example:

```
bool ChannelDataQueue::b_ChannelDataQueue_StartThread()
{
    DWORD threadID;

    m_hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ChannelDataQueue::u32_ChannelDataQueue_ReadChannelData, (LPVOID)this, CREATE_SUSPENDED, &threadID);

    // At this point, inspect the threadID in the debugger,
    // print it to the console, write it to a file, etc...

    CeSetThreadPriority(m_hThread,CE_THREAD_PRIO_256_HIGHEST);
    //SetThreadPriority(m_hThread,249);//248
    ResumeThread(m_hThread);

    return true;
}
```